# Add data in to database asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I want to add data into database and I get this error.

> An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: An error occurred while starting a transaction on the provider connection. See the inner exception for details.

Here is my code.

```
public void alarmlog(int id)
{
         AlarmLog log = new AlarmLog();

         if (id == 1)
         {
             log.SectorID = "LRD";
             log.LineNo = "L01";
             log.WorkStation = "02";
             log.LMQS = 1;
             log.StaffID = 6;
             log.DateTime = DateTime.Now;
         }

         db.AlarmLogs.Add(log);
         db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Put your code in try-catch block to get the error message details, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw.aspx

Comment: now i know my code is catch but i have no idea how to fix it

Comment: put  the screen shot of inner exception first

Comment: i try to add some data into database which have 
ID(int),
LineNo(string),
WorkStation(string),
LMQS(int),
StaffID(int),
DateTime(datetime)
what is detail of inner exception. sorry that i ask such a stupid question. i'm so new in asp.net mvc razor

Comment: If you're simply trying to see it within the editor -Visual studio, when the exception is thrown click 'View Detail' and expand the exception to see the InnerException. you can also see it programatically: `catch(Exception ex)
{
   Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException);
}`

Answer (score 0):

I have a hunch, that your error is located at your `if(id==1)` statement. My guess is, that you pass in an id which is not 1. A new `Alarmlog` is created, the if statement does not return true and then you attempt to add an empty Item to the database.
If all those fields, even one for that matter, may not be null, an exception does get thrown.

Remove your if-block and see if the error has vanished:

```
public void alarmlog(int id)
{
     AlarmLog log = new AlarmLog();

     log.SectorID = "LRD";
     log.LineNo = "L01";
     log.WorkStation = "02";
     log.LMQS = 1;
     log.StaffID = 6;
     log.DateTime = DateTime.Now;
     db.AlarmLogs.Add(log);
     db.SaveChanges();
}
```

If you want us to stop guessing, please do what the commenters said: wrap your code in `try { ... } catch(Exception ex) { ... }` blocks to see what the error is.

Comment: oh yeah i got it i just put db.SaveChanges(); in the loop. i call this function in foreach() loop that why i got this error. thank you for all answer and help :)